# How can I upgrade my 2.6.0 mongo to 2.6.latest?

Tags: mongodb

I am running ubuntu and have Mongo 2.6.0 installed.

Recently a new minor version of Mongo appeared (2.6.2), but for some reason I can not upgrade to it with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` (which I remember correctly upgraded minor versions when I was on 2.4.x version).

I assume that I can remove mongo and reinstall it, but this does not sound appealing.

Also I know that this question is not programming per se, but I think it will be useful for other people and also SO has a good mongo-community. (But if someone finds it really off-topic, please move it)

Here is the actual output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-34-23-80:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release             
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources            
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages      
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages  
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources     
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources 
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [58.5 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [20.6 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [4,727 B]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [61.3 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [21.5 kB]
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 168 kB in 2s (76.9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

When I do `sudo apt-cache policy mongodb-org` I see no information about `2.6.2` version.

```
mongodb-org:
  Installed: 2.6.0
  Candidate: 2.6.0
  Version table:
 *** 2.6.0 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: I think you probably had a shell or something open when you applied the upgrade. I've done that before. Exit all tools and maybe just try re-installing the "tools" package, or otherwise just process the install again. Remove first in the latter case.

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn, I have my dev machine and 2 servers and tried apt-getting a couple of times. It updates a lot of things but not mongo. The same situation is on all environments.

Comment: What I was getting at is you know it has not updated how? Is it just by the prompt from the shell? Or does the server version report in the logs to not be changed? What is the output from trying to run the apt-get upgrade? Does this even indicate the package was fetched or are there errors? I'm pretending your talking about your dev environment so this is not off topic, but you could really cover more in your question. Also look at all those things, there are logs for all of them.

Comment: I am typing `sudo apt-...` in terminal. It looks for possible updates, can not find anything related to mongo and that's it. I added the actual output in the question.

Comment: Just try `apt-get install mongodb` as a command. Make sure you have removed any of the `mongodb-10gen` packages and the only ones you should have are `mongodb-org`. Also look at your apt-get history like this `less /var/log/apt/history.log` in case there was a previous problem.

Comment: After trying to do `apt-get install mongodb` among other output I see `The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mongodb-org mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell
  mongodb-org-tools` which makes me uneasy. This is a dev version, so I can tolerate if everything will break, but I would rather ask before this.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command to update MongoDB to the latest version is:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

You can check the details about the package and it's versions with:

```
sudo apt-cache policy mongodb-org
```

It will display something like this:

```
mongodb-org:
  Installed: 2.6.1
  Candidate: 2.6.2
  Version table:
     2.6.2 0
        500 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen amd64 Packages
 *** 2.6.1 0
        500 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.6.0 0
        500 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/ dist/10gen amd64 Packages
```

The previous name of the package, from MongoDB repositories, was `mongodb-10gen` but it was renamed to `mongodb-org`.

If you try to install `mongo` package with:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
```

It will try to install the MongoDB from Ubuntu repositories (which is much older).

Be sure to always check the offical [installation page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) for updates to their repo location etc.

**Edit**

It seems that your package was installed manually from a deb package or the MongoDB repo was removed from the apt sources list.

Either way, adding the MongoDB repo back to sources list and then doing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

will install the newest version of the MongoDB (just for reference, link to the [official installation docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)).

Comment: Thanks for answer. For some reason I can not see 2.6.2 version when I do apt-cache policy. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Thank you Christian. I will try your suggestion +1. The problem is that I definitely have not installed from binary. But who knows, may be I forgot.

Comment: @SalvadorDali - sorry I meant `.deb` package.